# why do i get error TS2345 on directive definition?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I try to migrate an existing angular app to typescript (version 1.5.3):

Here is the code:

```
  'use strict';
    angular.module('x')
    .directive('tabsPane', TabsPane)

    function TabsPane(itemTabs) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: compileTabs
        };

        function compileTabs(tElement) {
            var template = createTabsTemplate(); //function which i don't include here for brevity
            tElement.append(template);
        }}
```

When i compile the javascript i get:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(itemTabs: any) => { restrict: string; compile: (tElement: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
>     Property 'push' is missing in type '(itemTabs: any) => { restrict: string; compile: (tElement: any) => void; }'.

I tried to understand why it complains here i went to the typescript definition of angular:

Somehow typescript implies this definition

> directive(name: string, inlineAnnotatedFunction: any[]): IModule;

where the following definition would be more appropriate:

> directive(name: string, directiveFactory: IDirectiveFactory): IModule;

I am totally new to typescript, so I assume that i make something wrong, but i can't find anything relevant with google.

Comment: Way late but: In my case it was som lingering cache that needed to be flushed. The solution for me was a bit hacky, but i set the return type to `:void` saved the file and then remove the return type and saved once again. Voila no more error.

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered the same problem while migrating from old javascript angularJs 1.4.9 code to typescript 2.6 code. I'm using @types/angular ver 1.6.39. I've added 'any' as return type of the parameter function like:

```
    angular.module("app")
      .directive("tabsPane", function TabsPane(itemTabs): any { 
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                compile: compileTabs
            };

            function compileTabs(tElement) {
                var template = createTabsTemplate();
                tElement.append(template);
            }
       });
```

The error disappeard :)

Answer (score 3):

When running compile in a directive, it must always return something, so in this case a simple `return true;` added to the bottom of your compile function would solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to update your version of angular.d.ts since in [the latest](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) I can see :

> directive(name: string, directiveFactory: IDirectiveFactory): IModule;

which will gives something like : `.directive('myCustomer', function(){...}` once compiled

just next to :

> directive(name: string, inlineAnnotatedFunction: any[]): IModule;

which will gives something like `.directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {...}` once compiled
(it actually changed in [this commit](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts), but it was a bug for a long time)

**Edit (since you seems to have the latest version of angular.d.ts)**

Try indicating the return type of your function by using this syntax :

`var TabsPane = (itemTabs) : ng.IDirectiveFactory => {}`

Comment: I have already the last version. I have both definitions in the tsd files, but typescript assumes that i want the first version

Comment: somehow the directive definition is problematic. When i change in Idirective from   compile?: IDirectiveCompileFn to   compile?: any; the problem is solved

Comment: have you tried doing : `var TabsPane = (itemTabs) : IDirectiveFactory => {}`

Comment: When trying this i get : error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IDirectiveFactory'.

Comment: sorry `ng.IDirectiveFactory` ?

Comment: I had the same problem and for me, setting the return type of my function to ng.IDirective resolved this. Thank @deKajoo